# When encrypting 2 Strings with XOR in Java, what is key[i % key.length]

Tags: java, string, encryption, xor

I'm trying to understand "encrypting" 2 Strings with XOR in Java, I've found [pretty clear example](https://github.com/KyleBanks/XOREncryption/blob/master/Java%20(Android%20compatible)/XOREncryption.java#L7) but I can't understand why they are doing this:

```
input.charAt(i) ^ key[i % key.length]
```

How in "human readable way" to descirbe `key[i % key.length]`, e.g. they are taking next chat from input and XOR-ing it with ...?

Whole method for "encrypting" with XOR is:

```
private static String encryptDecrypt(String input) {
    char[] key = {'K', 'C', 'Q'}; //Can be any chars, and any length array
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

    for(int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
        output.append((char) (input.charAt(i) ^ key[i % key.length]));
    }

    return output.toString();
}
```

Comment: What particularly is unclear to you?

Comment: In java, ``%`` is the modulo operator if that is what's confusing you...

Comment: The modulo operation in access of `key` ensures that `key` (which might be shorter than `input`) is repeatedly applied to `input`. E.g. in your case (where length of `key` == 3) `input[3] ^ key[0]`, `input[4] ^ key[1]`, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than XOR each character with the same value the algorithm uses a list of values. This way if your string is `EE` (for example) then the output encrypted string would contain two different characters, rather than the same character for each `E`. In this case the string would contain the characters with code `14` and `6`. The idea here is to prevent the same character always be encrypted with the same value.

The expression `key[i % key.length]` is used to select the next key from the array, and will wrap around to the first key when `i` goes past the end of that array.